# iOS: Share a run on Facebook

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-opengraph, facebook-ios-sdk

I am trying to share an activity that the user recorder to facebook, but just can't figure out how to get a nice GPS route of the run.

Here's what I have so far.
I can set the `fitness:metrics:location:latitude/longitude` and on facebook a map will appear with that location. But how would I be able to share a whole track? Is there a way to do that just using the FBSDKShareAPI?

```
    let properties = [
        "og:type": "fitness.course",
        "og:title": "ShareAPI Test-Course",
        "og:description": "This is a sample course.",
        "fitness:duration:value": 100,
        "fitness:duration:units": "s",
        "fitness:distance:value": 13,
        "fitness:distance:units": "km",
        "fitness:speed:value": 5,
        "fitness:speed:units": "m/s",
        "fitness:metrics:location:latitude": "41.40338",
        "fitness:metrics:location:longitude": "2.17403"
    ]


    let object = FBSDKShareOpenGraphObject(properties: properties)

    let action = FBSDKShareOpenGraphAction()
    action.actionType = "fitness.runs"
    action.setObject(object, forKey: "fitness:course")

    let content = FBSDKShareOpenGraphContent()
    content.action = action
    content.previewPropertyName = "fitness:course"

    FBSDKShareAPI.shareWithContent(content, delegate: self)
```

Where would I have to add all the trackpoints (`[FitnessActivityDataPoint]`)? I am a bit frustrated about the documentation on that stuff, cause I don't really get it.

Any help is very much appreciated!

EDIT:

If I wrap the metrics as array, it's also not working :(

```
"fitness:metrics": [
            [
                "fitness:metrics:location:latitude": "41.40338",
                "fitness:metrics:location:longitude": "2.17403",
                "fitness:metrics:location:altitude": "1",
                "fitness:metrics:timestamp": "2011-01-26T00:00"
            ],
            [
                "fitness:metrics:location:latitude": "41.60338",
                "fitness:metrics:location:longitude": "2.12403",
                "fitness:metrics:location:altitude": "1",
                "fitness:metrics:timestamp": "2011-01-26T01:00"
            ],
            ...
        ],
```

Comment: Ok... found it :)
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30581347/facebook-open-graph-object-with-large-course-objects-in-ios